# Jenkins - Pass checkout directory into ant as parameter

Tags: ant, jenkins

In Jenkins how do I specify the checkout directory as a parameter in a ANT call?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can pass the checkout directory as an Ant system property, as in (e.g. linux):

```
ant -Dcheckout.dir=${WORKSPACE}/[checkout dir] <target>
```

or on a Windows agent:

```
ant -Dcheckout.dir=%WORKSPACE%/[checkout dir] <target>
```

The checkout directory is what you specified in the scm settings for your project. It can very well be the root directory of your workspace ".", or some explicit sub-folder.

Then, within your ant script, the path for the checkout dir will be available under the ${checkout.dir} property.